# Algorithm on computing hashcode for floating point value?

Tags: algorithm, hashcode

I was looking for an algorithm that computes hashcode for float type or float object. I was searching on the web for quite some time now, but what I get are on a layer of abstraction like Java's floatToRawBits, in which I do not know the internal implementation of Java's hashcode for Float. What I'd actually like to have is an implementation, not an interface.

I know it may seem strange, but I do need this right now. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided the size of the hashcode, I believe it's a bit of a crucial part here.

Comment: Source is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Float.java#Float.floatToRawIntBits%28float%29). Looks like the actual method called is native code.

Answer (score 0):

My javadocs say that `floatToRawIntBits`:

```
/**
 * Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value
 * according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit
 * layout, preserving Not-a-Number (NaN) values.
 *
 * <p>Bit 31 (the bit that is selected by the mask
 * {@code 0x80000000}) represents the sign of the floating-point
 * number.
 * Bits 30-23 (the bits that are selected by the mask
 * {@code 0x7f800000}) represent the exponent.
 * Bits 22-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask
 * {@code 0x007fffff}) represent the significand (sometimes called
 * the mantissa) of the floating-point number.
 */
```

Looks easy. Then see `Float.floatToIntBits(value)` implementation:

```
int result = floatToRawIntBits(value);

// Check for NaN based on values of bit fields, maximum
// exponent and nonzero significand.
if ( ((result & FloatConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK) ==
      FloatConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK) &&
     (result & FloatConsts.SIGNIF_BIT_MASK) != 0)
    result = 0x7fc00000;
return result;
```

Comment: Well I saw these too, but aint helpful at all. The docblocks on floatToRawIntBits do not tell how exactly it is implemented, ideally I can view the native C code to see how it is done.

Comment: Then see @Trengot answer, it looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation will depend on the JVM/JDK you are using. For openJDK the source is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native/java/lang/Float.c). From the license given, it looks like openJDK and Oracle use the same code.

The method for `floatToRawIntBits` is

```
/*
 * Find the bit pattern corresponding to a given float, NOT collapsing NaNs
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Float_floatToRawIntBits(JNIEnv *env, jclass unused, jfloat v)
{
    union {
        int i;
        float f;
    } u;
    u.f = (float)v;
    return (jint)u.i;
}
```